# Azure Managed instance failover with transnational replication

Tags: azure, transactional-replication, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have two azure SQL managed instances in different region and configured fail-over group between the same MI instances. Also configured the transactional replication between on-prem sql \ Azure IaaS VM to primary managed instance. Now want to test fail-over group by failing over to secondary and then to primary. What's the best way \ possible way so that replication should not get disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

If geo-replication is enabled on a publisher or distributor instance in a failover group, the managed instance administrator must clean up all publications on the old primary and reconfigure them on the new primary after a failover occurs. Please refer [MS doucumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transactional-replication#with-failover-groups) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the subscriber, use the **failover group read/write listener endpoint** instead of the primary managed instance name.

[image]

The following information is available in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/replication-transactional-overview#with-failover-groups) on this subject:

"If a subscriber SQL Managed Instance is in a failover group, the publication should be configured to connect to the failover group listener endpoint for the subscriber managed instance. In the event of a failover, subsequent action by the managed instance administrator depends on the type of failover that occurred:

- For a failover with no data loss, replication will continue working
  after failover.
- For a failover with data loss, replication will work as well. It will
  replicate the lost changes again.
- For a failover with data loss, but the data loss is outside of the
  distribution database retention period, the SQL Managed Instance
  administrator will need to reinitialize the subscription database."